# Java Connect To SqlServer Database

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server database using Eclipse but it's giving me the error:

```
Cannot open database "AdventureWorks2012" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `integratedSecurity=true` it means that you windows account is not allowed to access `AdventureWorks2012` database. You need to grant the Windows account you are logged in (or running Eclipse) the database access rights. You can follow [To configure database access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172405(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_0) docs to grant your Windows account access:

> 1. On the computer that is running SQL Server, start SQL Server Management Studio. In the Registered Servers pane, double-click SQL Server.
> 2. In the object explorer pane, expand SQL Server, expand the Security folder, right-click Logins, and then click New Login.
> 3. In the Login – New dialog box, specify either Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication mode.
> 4. If you are using Windows Authentication, enter a logon name and select either the Grant Access or the Deny Access option.
> 5. If you are using SQL Server Authentication, type a logon name and password, and then confirm the password.
> 6. In the left pane, click Database Access.
> 7. In the right pane, select the Permit check box for the databases you are granting access to, and then click OK.

If you want to connect by specifying username and password use `integratedSecurity=false` and supply username and password as shown in the [Establishing a Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) docs:

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver:...";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", <database username>);
props.put("password", <database password>);
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, props)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i connect to the sql server database with the windows account , that's why i use integratedSecurity=true  because i think that my windows account already have all the permission to access any database in the sql server !! , any way can you tel me haw i grant the rights access to my windows account in the sql server data base !!

Comment: @Wahib update the answer but the actual steps will vary depending on the SQL Server version setup.

Comment: i'm using sql server 2017

Comment: i grant all the access to windows account in the SSMS but i still get the same error